# Why can't I return a rational number from the method in this Java program?

Tags: java, class, methods

```
 public Rational max (Rational r) 
{
    double float1 = numerator/denominator;
    double float2 = r.getNumerator()/r.getDenominator();
    if (float1>float2)
    return float1;
    else
    return float2;
}

public double floatvalue(Rational r)
{
    double den = denominator * r.getDenominator();
    double num = numerator * r.getDenominator() + r.getNumerator() * denominator;
    return num/den;
}
```

My second method (floatvalue) allows me to return num/den even though they are double variables. However, it wont let me return float1 or float2 because they are double values. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Your first method is expecting to return a Rational, you want it to be a double

Comment: All I see are floats.  Why aren't you writing a Rational abstraction?  Sorry, this is irrational.

Comment: Thank you I feel like an idiot

Comment: @Justin: Just try a bit harder and you won't, that's the exact purpose of an exercise! Try to understand what  user1875195 and your compiler are telling you. Online resource like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_type may also help you figure out what's wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The method **max()** is of type **Rational**, so it's going to return a **Rational** object (and that's why it can't return a **double** value). **float1** and **float2** are the result of **denominator/numerator** which are variables of the class **Rational**. You want to check which Rational number is greater. To do so, you shouldn't be returning the result of the division, but the numbers themselves. And, in this program, a rational number is represented by a **Rational** class object. So, if the Rational number **r** is greater than the current rational number (i.e., the **Rational** object that calls the instance method **max()**), you'd be returning **r**. Else, you'd return the current object. To do that, just modify the **if-else** statement in the definition of **max()** into the one below.

```
if(float1>float2)
return this; //returns the current object
else
return r;
```

I'd also like you to note one more thing. In case the variables **numerator** and **denominator** of class **Rational** are of type **int**, then do modify the division in this manner:

```
double float1 = (double)numerator/(double)denominator;
```

and also

```
double float2 = (double)r.getNumerator()/(double)r.getDenominator();
```

if the methods **getNumerator()** and **getDenominator()** are also of type **int**. This is to avoid division of two integers because if that happens, the fractional part of the result will be ignored and the result will also be an integer. So, **0.00125** will turn to **0** and if both **float1** and **float2** become **0**, then you'll get a runtime error thrown in the **max()** that says that no value is returned.

Hope you understand my explanation.

---

**EDIT:** I wrote an example program that could help you understand the concept better. [Click here to see the program](http://mysticpaste.com/view/SiHj7he7E3;jsessionid=1shsm8vglfv6a1p9i0ykepp1m3?2)